# Google Cloud / standard Appengine : running application locally fails

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have started a new project using Google Cloud/Java/Standard AppEngine. This very simple project contains endpoints/API as per Google Cloud Endpoints framework. When running on the cloud, everything works as expected. When running locally, it doesn't start at all and I get that exception below:

```
juil. 27, 2017 3:37:32 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFOS: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'd:\devtools\CloudSDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'D:\workspaces\googlecloud\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\jaime-sortir\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
2017-07-27 15:37:32.782:INFO::main: Logging initialized @907ms
2017-07-27 15:37:33.236:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
2017-07-27 15:37:37.496:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=3911ms
2017-07-27 15:37:38.133:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@2d6764b2{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Platform
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Ticker$1.read(Ticker.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsedNanos(Stopwatch.java:181)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Stopwatch.java:194)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.elapsedNanos(LocalCache.java:3665)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2381)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2336)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2294)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2207)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4062)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4066)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4995)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5001)
    at com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceImpl.getAccessToken(AppIdentityServiceImpl.java:272)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:98)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:243)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.fetchLatestServiceVersion(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:154)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.fetch(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:125)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.get(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:110)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.get(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:49)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Suppliers$ExpiringMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:199)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigFetcher.fetch(ServiceConfigFetcher.java:41)
    at com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter$1.load(ServiceManagementConfigFilter.java:33)
    at com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter.init(ConfigFilter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:346)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ManualInstanceHolder.startUp(ManualInstanceHolder.java:77)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:271)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:359)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:223)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
```

I'm starting my local server from Eclispe/Windows 7. As per the stacktrace, it looks like it crashes when processing Oauth2 stuffs (API is not restricted but it refers to some security objects).

I have been googling this issue on Google and found nothing. I have another sample project without any endpoints which runs fine on Windows. Below is my pom.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>zango.jaimesortir</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaimesortir-api</artifactId>

    <!-- <parent> <artifactId>appengine-java8-samples</artifactId> <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId> 
        <version>1.0.0</version> <relativePath>..</relativePath> </parent> -->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <endpoints.framework.version>2.0.7</endpoints.framework.version>
        <endpoints.management.version>1.0.4</endpoints.management.version>

        <endpoints.project.id>xxxxx</endpoints.project.id>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>

        <appengine.maven.plugin>1.3.1</appengine.maven.plugin>

        <appengine.version>1.9.54</appengine.version>
        <appengine.sdk.version>1.9.54</appengine.sdk.version>

        <!-- <project.http.version>1.19.0</project.http.version> <project.oauth.version>1.19.0</project.oauth.version> -->

        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>

    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.3.9</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
            <version>${endpoints.management.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>GetSwaggerDoc</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>GetSwaggerDoc</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                            <mainClass>com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>get-swagger-doc</argument>
                                <argument>--hostname=echo-api.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.cloud.goog</argument>
                                <argument>--war=target/jaimesortir-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT</argument>
                                <argument>zango.jaimesortir.api.LocationApi</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
                                <artifactId>endpoints-framework-tools</artifactId>
                                <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                                <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
                                <version>${appengine.sdk.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After posting my question, I double checked and noticed that I forgot executing the following command as stated in the tutorial

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Now, it starts. Thank to anybody who tried to help.